# Find the functions which the following power series represent

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, power-series, uniform-convergence

By integration, differentiation, or any other valid operation : I am asked to find the function which these represent

$$\sum_1^\infty n^2x^n$$

I tried doing everything - but I just can't do it. What I've done so far :

The series is convergent $<=>$ $-1<x<1$
And uniformly convergent on  a compact set $K \subset (-1,1)$ So I can use the property of uniformly convergent series to use differentiation integration etc. But I couldn't move a pencil. Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that
$$ x\frac{d}{dx} x^n = nx^n, $$
so this can be found by applying $xd/dx$ twice to $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} x^n = \frac{1}{1-x} $ in the region of absolute convergence.

Answer (score 0):

We may consider that
$$ f(x,t)\stackrel{\text{def}}{=}\sum_{n\geq 1} e^{nt} x^n = \frac{x e^t}{1-x e^t} \tag{1}$$
as soon as $\left|x e^t\right|<1$. By applying $\frac{\partial^2}{\partial t^2}$ to both sides, then evaluating at $t=0$,
$$ \sum_{n\geq 1} n^2 x^n = \left.\frac{\partial^2}{\partial t^2}\left(\frac{x e^t}{1-x e^t}\right)\right|_{t=0} = \left.\frac{x e^t(1+x e^t)}{(1-x e^t)^3}\right|_{t=0}=\color{red}{\frac{x(1+x)}{(1-x)^3}}.\tag{2}$$
On the other hand, since $n^2$ is a second-degree polynomial in the $n$ variable, we know in advance that
$$ (1-x)^3 \sum_{n\geq 1} n^2 x^n = \sum_{n\geq 1}\left(p(n)-3p(n-1)+3p(n-2)+p(n-3)\right) x^n$$
is a polynomial in $x$ with degre $\leq 2$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $x=e^{-\theta}$, then
$$\sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}}n^{2}x^n=\sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}}n^{2}e^{-\theta{n}}=$$
$$=\frac{\partial^{2}}{\partial{\theta}^{2}}\sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}}e^{-\theta{n}}=\frac{\partial^{2}}{\partial{\theta}^{2}}[\frac{1}{1-e^{-\theta}}-1]=$$
$$=-\frac{\partial}{\partial{\theta}}\frac{e^{-\theta}}{(1-e^{-\theta})^{2}}=$$
$$=\frac{e^{-\theta}(1-e^{-\theta})^{2}+2(1-e^{-\theta})e^{-2\theta}}{(1-e^{-\theta})^{4}}=$$
$$=\frac{x}{(1-x)^{2}}+\frac{2x^{2}}{(1-x)^{3}}$$