# Sum of Infinite series $\frac{1.3}{2}+\frac{3.5}{2^2}+\frac{5.7}{2^3}+\frac{7.9}{2^4}+......$

Tags: sequences-and-series

Prove that the sum of the infinite series $\frac{1.3}{2}+\frac{3.5}{2^2}+\frac{5.7}{2^3}+\frac{7.9}{2^4}+......$ is 23.

My approach 
I got the following term
$S_n=\sum_1^\infty\frac{4n^2}{2^n}-\sum_1^\infty\frac{1}{2^n}$.

For $\sum_1^\infty\frac{1}{2^n}$ the answer is 1 as it forms a geometric series but I am bot able to find the solution to $\sum_1^\infty\frac{4n^2}{2^n}$.

Comment: Do you mean $1.3$ (a decimal) or $1\cdot 3$ (a product)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$\frac{1.3}{2}+\frac{3.5}{2^2}+\frac{5.7}{2^3}+\frac{7.9}{2^4}+…=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty }\frac{(2n-1)(2n+1)}{2^n}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty }\frac{(4n^2-1)}{2^n}$$
depending on the geometric series
$$\frac{1}{1-x}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty }x^n$$
$$(\frac{1}{1-x})'=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty }nx^{n-1}$$
$$x(\frac{1}{1-x})'=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty }nx^{n}$$
$$(x(\frac{1}{1-x})')'=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty }n^2x^{n-1}$$
$$x(x(\frac{1}{1-x})')'=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty }n^2x^{n}$$
$$4x(x(\frac{1}{1-x})')'=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty }4n^2x^{n}$$
$$4x(x(\frac{1}{1-x})')'-\frac{1}{1-x}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty }4n^2x^{n}-\sum_{n=0}^{\infty }x^n$$
$$4x(x(\frac{1}{1-x})')'-\frac{1}{1-x}+1=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty }4n^2x^{n}-\sum_{n=1}^{\infty }x^n$$
so
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty }x^n(4n^2-1)=\frac{4x^2+4x}{(1-x)^3}-\frac{x}{1-x}$$
now let $x=1/2$ to get $23$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**. One may used this
$$\sum_{n\ge1}n^{2}x^n=\frac{x}{(1-x)^{2}}+\frac{2x^{2}}{(1-x)^{3}},\qquad |x|<1,$$ proved for example [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2162662/find-the-functions-which-the-following-power-series-represent).

Hope you can take from here.